# Jenkins create job from cli

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm using Jenkins 2.204.1 and trying to create a job from CLI get an error:

```
java  -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8091/jenkins get-job prova > prova.xml

java  -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8091/jenkins create-job pippo < prova.xml
```

> ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing create-job
>   command. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
>   at org.xml.sax.helpers.NewInstance.newInstance(NewInstance.java:82) at
>   org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:228)
>   Caused: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
>   at
>   org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:230)
>   at
>   org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:191)
>   at jenkins.util.xml.XMLUtils.safeTransform(XMLUtils.java:66) at
>   hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn.createProjectFromXML(ItemGroupMixIn.java:274)
>   Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to persist config.xml at
>   hudson.model.ItemGroupMixIn.createProjectFromXML(ItemGroupMixIn.java:294)
>   at jenkins.model.Jenkins.createProjectFromXML(Jenkins.java:3966) at
>   hudson.cli.CreateJobCommand.run(CreateJobCommand.java:72) at
>   hudson.cli.CLICommand.main(CLICommand.java:251) at
>   hudson.cli.CLIAction$PlainCliEndpointResponse$1.run(CLIAction.java:218)
>   at
>   jenkins.util.FullDuplexHttpService.download(FullDuplexHttpService.java:115)
>   at
>   jenkins.util.FullDuplexHttpService$Response.generateResponse(FullDuplexHttpService.java:175)
>   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponseRenderer$Default.handleHttpResponse(HttpResponseRenderer.java:124)
>   .....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: prova.xml might contain some unique values that you cannot import without editing them before hand. As a general rule, I would suggest to go full pipeline + jobDSL. I made a lib to abstract the jobDSL part https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-pipelayer/

Comment: prova.xml come from a job created using Jenkins GUI and it contains a simply bash command echo "hello". How can it contain not valid values?